# Is there a document/page that indicates how much transmission rates are from each planet, currently?

Tags: data-transmission

Eg from Mars with the IPN, the DSN, what data rates we can get from [insert satellite/probe/rover] at that location - how much data can they transmit to earth currently?

Comment: Not directly related but maybe interesting too: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28401/25911

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is quite what you're asking (for theoretical data throughput to a spacecraft of your choice?), but it might be close/get you some information that you want.

[DSN Now](https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html) shows the current link status of each of the DSN antennas.  There's a "more detail" function that will let you expand the link status to see bitrate and power.  Here's an example image of DSN 63 (Madrid) talking to the LUCY mission, showing 352.9 kilobits/second at a received power of 1.49E-17 kW.  Which is not very much power.

[image: Screenshot of DSN Now as described in the paragraph above]

Comment: That's plenty of power! If you click on VGR1, you see that Voyager 1 is sending us 160 (bytes/bits?) per second, at  2.29E-22 kW. (You may have to scout around -- that site is not the easiest to navigate.)

Comment: I personally don't trust any level of power that's most easily expressed as billion-billionths of a kilowatt

Comment: I agree that 2.29E-19W would be more logical.